# Code not reaching if statement

Tags: android, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
public void click(View v)
{
    Button b = (Button) v;
    TextView viewEditText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.functionTextView);
    String editText = viewEditText.getText().toString();

    if (b.getId() == R.id.backspace)
    {
        if (viewEditText.length() > 0)
        {
            if (editText.substring(editText.length() - 1, editText.length()) == ".")
            {
                periodTrue = false;
            }
            viewEditText.setText(viewEditText.getText().toString().substring(0, viewEditText.length() - 1));
        }
    }
}
```

In this code I check to see if the character being backspaced is a period, if the previous condition is true. It sets the variable periodTrue to false. This tells the app that another period can be added.

Everything works with the <kbd>backspace</kbd> key as normal, except it never makes it inside the if statement where the variable is set. It throws no errors and I have checked with

`viewEditText.append(editText.subString(editText.length()-1, editText.length());` to verify that the returned character is ".".

I don't know why it's not working, and it throws no errors or warnings either, on compile or run time. So I've come to you to see if a different perspective can show what I'm obviously doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (editText.substring(editText.length() - 1, editText.length()) == ".")
```

This won't work as you're comparing the *references* of the two `String`s, which will be different. (More in-depth explanation in this question: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java))

Use the following instead:

```
if (".".equals(editText.substring(editText.length() - 1, editText.length())))
```

Comment: This works like a charm. I appreciate you giving me the link to explain the different comparisons. My code now does what I would expect. Thanks :)